# What is "becoming carbon positive"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "reducing carbon emission"?

> The company has increasingly focused on sustainability as it works towards *its goal of **becoming carbon positive** by 2030*, and in November it started buying back and reselling UK customers' used furniture to counter the mass consumption associated with Black Friday.

[[Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/ikea-catalog-finished-ended-online-store-swedish-furniture-2020-12)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Carbon Positive' is a term to describe a city (or possibly any eco-system) where target levels of waste carbon are being recycled instead of emitted into the atmosphere. If a city is described as 'Carbon Positive' it has achieved the targets set out by the framework.